# Padding is not defined in d3.js

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I'm trying to get day of the month(i.e 1,2,3,4 ...etc) on the x axis and time period of the hour 0-24 on Y axis. I am unable to get the axis line i dont know why.Can someone tell me why? In the console window, it says padding is not defined.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>

    /*set the axis line color, dot stroke, font size, and font position*/
    body {
      font: 13px helvetica;
    }

    .name{
      position: relative;
      top: 90px;
      text-align: left;
      font-weight: bold;
    }

    .title {
      position: relative;
      text-align: left;
      font-size: 25px;
    }

    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .dot {
      stroke: #000;
    }

    #filter {
      position: absolute;
    }

    #mark {
      padding-left: 150px;
      position: inherit;
    }

    #xAXs {
      position: relative;
      left: 290px;
      bottom: 30px;
    }

    #yAXs {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 315px;

    }

    #label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 599px;
    bottom: 125px;
    left: 300px;
    right: 0px;
    }

    #label2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 599px;
    bottom: 125px;
    left: 430px;
    right: 0px;
    }

    </style>

    <body>


    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

    <script>

    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


    var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);


    var color = d3.scale.category10();

    var axisNames = { 
                        Hour: 'Hour', 
                        Day: 'Day',
                    };  





    // define the x scale (horizontal)
    var mindate = new Date(2012,0,1),
        maxdate = new Date(2012,0,31);

    var xScale = d3.time.scale()
                .domain([mindate, maxdate])    // values between for month of january
            .range([padding, width - padding * 2]);   // map these the the chart width = total width minus padding at both sides    

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale)
        .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left");

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


    d3.csv("file1.csv", function(error, data) {
      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.Day = +d.Day;
        d.Hour = +d.Hour;
      });

      x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Day; })).nice();
      y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Hour; })).nice();

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis)
        .append("text")
          .attr("class", "label")
          .attr("x", width)
          .attr("y", -6)
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text("Day");

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
          .attr("class", "label")
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
          .attr("y", 6)
          .attr("dy", ".71em")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text("Hour")

     var circles = svg.selectAll(".dot")
          .data(data)
        .enter().append("circle")
          .attr("class", "dot")
          .attr("r", 3.5)
          .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.Hour); })
          .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.day); })
          .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });


      var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
          .data(color.domain())
          .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "legend")
          .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });


      legend.append("rect")
          .attr("x", width - 18)
          .attr("width", 18)
          .attr("height", 18)
          .style("fill", color);


      legend.append("text")
          .attr("x", width - 24)
          .attr("y", 9)
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text(function(d) { return d; });



      d3.selectAll("[name=v]").on("change", function() {
          var selected = this.value;
          display = this.checked ? "inline" : "none";


      svg.selectAll(".dot")
          .filter(function(d) {return selected == d.name;})
          .attr("display", display);
          });



      d3.selectAll("[name=sepal]").on("change", function(d) {
         radius = this.value;

         svg.selectAll(".dot")
         console.log(radius);
         circles.attr("r", function(d) { return d[radius]; });
      });



      d3.select("[name=xAX]").on("change", function(){
        xAxy = this.value;
        console.log(xAxy)
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d[xAxy]; })).nice();

        svg.select(".x.axis").transition().call(xAxis);

        svg.selectAll(".dot").transition().attr("cx", function(d) { 
            return x(d[xAxy]);
        });
        svg.selectAll(".x.axis").selectAll("text.label").text(axisNames[xAxy] + " (cm)");
      });

      d3.select("[name=yAX]").on("change", function(){
        yAxy = this.value;
        console.log(yAxy)
        y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d[yAxy]; })).nice();
        svg.select(".y.axis").transition().call(yAxis);
        svg.selectAll(".dot").transition().attr("cy", function(d) { 
            return y(d[yAxy]);
        });
        svg.selectAll(".y.axis").selectAll("text.label").text(axisNames[yAxy] + " (cm)");
      });

    });

    </script>
    <br><br>
      <br>
    </body>
```

Comment: Well, that's because `padding` is not defined!

Comment: Can you help me here? Padding is default in CSS right?

Answer (score 1):

You set a time scale in which the range uses `padding` and `width`:

```
var xScale = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([mindate, maxdate])
    .range([padding, width - padding * 2]);
```

Despite you had previously defined `width`:

```
width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right;
```

You didn't define `padding` anywhere in your code.

So, just give it any value you want, *before* defining the time scale:

```
var padding = 42; //tweak this value
```